# Expression to say that you did something better than before

Tags: expressions

I remember that there's an expression in English for this situation but I can't remember which one. Three weeks ago I did my best drawing ever, and now I did one better. This is what's coming up "I think I topped it off with this one" but I don't think it's the correct one. Which one is the correct one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could it be *personal best* as in your *new personal best*?

How about *[surpassed](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/surpass)* or *[eclipsed](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/eclipse)*?

Comment: That definitely conveys the idea... I remember there was a verb but oh well... personal best works.

Comment: Please see my edit.

Comment: Seems like 'surpassed' would seem a very vain thing to say about oneself.  It works nicely as a compliment about someone else though.

Answer (score 2):

"You've outdone yourself again."

Answer (score 0):

You've *trumped yourself* or *outdone yourself*.